# VBA: Looping a condition through a range that compares values from other columns until the list ends

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Public Sub MainTOfomat()
Dim ShippingQty As Range
Dim ReceivedQty As Range
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:P").AutoFit
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:P").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="No"
    ActiveSheet.Range("K:L").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
    Set ShippingQty = Range("K2")
    Set ReceivedQty = ShippingQty.Offset(0, 1)
    ShippingQty.Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ShippingQty.Value = 0 Then
            ShippingQty.Offset(0, 5) = "Needs Fulfillment"
        ElseIf ShippingQty.Value > ReceivedQty.Value Then
            ShippingQty.Offset(0, 5) = "Needs Receipt"
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

The code is program is supposed to loop though each row in the column and fill in the statement based on the result of the condition for values in two other columns. The problem is that the loop goes through, but only the first line actually changes, and the auto filter code before the loop gets skipped.

Comment: your first filter filters for "No". then you are starting a 2nd filter that filters non-blanks. Maybe keep the same filter and set the field for 12 for the non-blanks

Comment: then you mix `ShippingQty` and `ActiveCell` references.  After the first loop they are not the same thing.

Comment: @Davesexcel I didn't know you could auto filter two different columns at once.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see. After the first loop, the active cells are now in the ShippingQty.Offset(0, 5) range and no longer in the ShippingQty range. Does that mean that I should change to loop so that it starts and goes through the offset range?

Comment: find the last cell in column K that has data and use a standard for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your macro fixed up.
As mentioned before your `ShippingQty` range and `ReceivedQty` do not change with the activecell. When moving to the next cell, that is the activecell. The filter range need to be the same. A:P is filtered, when changing to K:L ,field 2 actually becomes column B, so if you want to filter out non-blanks in column L you need the field 12.

```
Sub YourMacro()
    
    Dim ShippingQty As Range
    Dim ReceivedQty As Range
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:P").AutoFit
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:P")
        .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="No"
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>"
    End With
    Set ShippingQty = Range("K2")
    Set ReceivedQty = ShippingQty.Offset(0, 1)
    ShippingQty.Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If ActiveCell.Rows.Hidden = False Then
            If ActiveCell.Value = 0 Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = "Needs Fulfillment"
            ElseIf ActiveCell.Value > ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = "Needs Receipt"
            End If
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
    Loop
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0
End Sub
```

---

You can use this option as well without using selects.

```
Sub Option1()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    
    With ws
        
        Set rng = .Range("K2:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        With .Range("A:P")
            .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="No"
            .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>"
        End With
        For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            If c = 0 Then c.Offset(, 5) = "Needs Fulfillments"
            If c > c.Offset(, 1) Then c.Offset(, 5) = "Needs Receipts"
            
        Next c
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```